# AttributeKeyID collisions when loading github project with sbt

Tags: scala, sbt

I tried to pull in external dependency on github project:

```
object HelloBuild extends Build {
  lazy val root = Project(id = "hello", base = file(".")) dependsOn
                  (RootProject( uri("git://github.com/Rogach/s4gnuplot")))
}
```

It is also built with sbt, and also has sbt-revolver plugin.

And I get the following message:

```
[error] AttributeKey ID collisions detected for: 'start' 
        (sbt.InputTask[cc.spray.revolver.AppProcess], 
         sbt.InputTask[cc.spray.revolver.AppProcess])
```

Removing sbt-revolver plugin from the outer project makes build work.

Is there a way to work around this?

EDIT: This seems to be a bug in sbt: [#329](https://github.com/harrah/xsbt/issues/329)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The simplest way would be to checkout `s4gnuplot` and `publish` (or just `publish-local`) a binary package, then depend on that in the normal way with `libraryDependencies`.

Comment: That'll work, but I want to depend exactly on the github source. And checking out every time something changed is not so good.